# Using try catch exception handling in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, exception, try-catch, laravel-6

In my app, this is the RegisterController,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
            'last_name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],

        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],

        ]);
    }
}
```

I have done the basic validations here.

But now I would like to know how to use try catch exception handling to handle the controller errors and if an error occurred how to redirect user back to register blade? Can I use try catch exception handling here? Or is this secure enough?

I'm using laravel 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest way to be working with Validation is to utilize FormRequests.

```
class CreateUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
            'last_name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        ];
    }
}
```

In your controller outwards facing method, utilise it (seems like create is protected and can't find the store function). This will automatically redirect and validate, without any extra code.

```
public function create(CreateUserRequest $request, array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
    ]);
}
```

You can then check for validation errors in blade like so, as described in the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors).

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```